# Lubuntu 19.04 Battery Icon unchanged

Tags: lubuntu, icons, battery

The battery icon often remains unchanged as I plug and unplug my laptop. Also, the low battery indication does not work at all. I'm running Lubuntu 19.04. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I know this may be a bug regarding my BIOS and hardware not interacting with Lubuntu.

Comment: https://manual.lubuntu.me/3/3.2/3.2.12/power_management.html is the manual page for Power Management (it maybe useful in raising the % low-cutoff)    I've made a bug report relating to a battery issue (1845761) but yours *feels* more like the indicator was a little slow being updated (I've seen this a couple of times too; once I detected the pattern on which it updated I was happy and have since ignored it).

Comment: Well, my indicator is not slow it simply doesn't change from being fully charged. As in it freezes. So this is a known issue (1845761)?

Comment: If you believe it's a bug, please report it (`ubuntu-bug lxqt-powermanagement`). The bug I mentioned https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxqt-powermanagement/+bug/1845761 has only been detected once http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/reports/bugs/1845761 in QA-testing so no it's not confirmed.  In that bug the stats showed 0 as if frozen, until logout/login was done. It's not your release but same package (0.14.1-0ubuntu1) .  I'd suggest `ubuntu-bug` reporting yours so more details can be provided by `apport` even if later marked duplicate.

Comment: I will do. I found this article https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2411020, and in it people seem to have this issue: "ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored"

not that I really know what this is, but my computer says the same thing

Comment: :)   I'd seen that (ubuntuforums) before; but my eepc won't boot thumbdrives thus I didn't investigate.  I didn't find any reported bugs to investigate though (that would have made me workaround the eepc booting issue).  Bugs are of no importance until reported.

Comment: I should mention it resets upon reboot, or starts working for a bit until plugged in again.